# How to create autocomplete from sql in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, autocomplete

hi  first of all sorry for my english i have this codes to get data in input and show in list when user types 
but my data is in the sql database in phpmyadmin im new in php 
i want to create autocomplete from sql in php but i dont khnow how there is tons of examples out there in google but none of them is for utf-8 charset
in my database has utf-8 words so i cant do it

this works for me but without sql

```
(function( $ ) {
var proto = $.ui.autocomplete.prototype,
initSource = proto._initSource;

function filter( array, term ) {
var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(term), "i" );
return $.grep( array, function(value) {
    return matcher.test( $( "<div>" ).html( value.label || value.value ||         
value ).text() );
});
}

$.extend( proto, {
_initSource: function() {
    if ( this.options.html && $.isArray(this.options.source) ) {
        this.source = function( request, response ) {
            response( filter( this.options.source, request.term ) );
        };
    } else {
        initSource.call( this );
    }
},

_renderItem: function( ul, item) {
    return $( "<li></li>" )
        .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
        .append( $( "<a></a>" )[ this.options.html ? "html" : "text" ](         
item.label ) )
        .appendTo( ul );
}
});
})( jQuery );

$(function() {
    var availableTags = [
        { label: 'سیب', value:'سیب' }, //<===utf-8
        { label: '2سیب', value:'سیب2' },//<===utf-8
        { label: 'Apple3', value:'Apple3' }             
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags,
        html: 'html'
    });
});
```

i got the code form here:
http://jsfiddle.net/eay3d/1/

Comment: it would be helpful to know what the fields in your database were called. You could just do a loop (in php) to produce the availableTags array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fill out the JQuery array using PHP. Without knowing the more info about the table I can't give you complete/working code but it would look something like this:

```
var availableTags = [
<?php
$queryString = "SELECT * FROM `table`"; // I don't know what your table is called
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $queryString) or die('Unable to execute query. ' . mysqli_error($conn));
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
echo "{ label: '" . $row['dataLable'] . "', value:'" . $row['dataValue'] . "' },"; // I don't know what your fields are called
}
?>           
];
```

This example would also need your database connection setup correctly. You can read about that on W3Schools: [Open a Connection to MySQL](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp)

Comment: I'm assuming (by the way) that the database is actually MySQL and not SQL. My basis being that the OP mentioned PHPMyAdmin.